# MAPI_E_CALL_FAILED (0x80004005) when try to access MAPI via windows service

Tags: c#, email, windows-services, mapi

I've developed a windows service which is designed to communicate with a mvc web application via SignalR.
In this specific case the user want's to send an email, with predefined text/subject and some attachements.
The mvc application passes an identifier to the service, which in return calls the api with the identifier, to get the files/attachements.
It stores them to a temporary directory for later use.

If the download is completed, then the service will call MAPI to pass the mail object to the standard mail client.

To be clear: it works fine, as designed, when it is not running as a service, but an console application (for example) instead.
If I run it as a service, I always get a MAPI_E_CALL_FAILED (0x80004005), no matter what I do.

```
public static extern HRESULT MAPILogon(IntPtr hwnd, string prf, string pw, int flg, int rsv, ref IntPtr sess);
```

in my application i then call:

```
var status = SimpleMAPIWrapper.MAPILogon(connection.Hwnd, connection.Profile, connection.Password, connection.Flags, 0, ref zero);
```

after that status contains the error code/message: **MAPI_E_CALL_FAILED**

If I run it inside a console application, I always get **S_OK** (0x00000000), which is what I expected.

First I thought it may be that no mail client was associated when running as system/network service. But it always fails, when running the service as the same user as when running it as console application.

Any idea, what I am missing?

EDIT: This solution should not just work with outlook, but any third party mail client.

Comment: You must use MAPILogonEx and follow [the guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839856.aspx) if your going via a service such as using MAPI_NO_MAIL.  If at all possible I would try to use SmtpClient instead.

Comment: So instead of calling MAPILogon i should implement MAPILogonEx?
And I can't use SmtpClient here, since won't send any data from our server. All of the content should simply be passed to the standard mail client, nothing else.

Comment: What is in the default profile for the user whose identity your service is running under?

Comment: Normally it is running as system or network service. What do you mean by default profile?

EDIT: it should not only work with outlook. Actually I am testing with Thunderbird

Comment: @Thyrador I have the same problem but only on Win10, Win8.1 and Win7 works perfectly. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @Daniel W. I ditched this approach so I went to use a task instead. It will get fired once the user was logged on. This way I also can add user specific informations to the task. Downside of this approach will be that you have to add/install a task for everyone, replacing the service approach, or one for each user.